# Android sharedpreferences into arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I created a simple game. At the end the user's name and score is supposed to get into a highscore list. For this i would like to store these data in sharedpreferences. I saw a post and i am trying to apply it to my app but it force closes. I don't even know if this is the right thing i am doing. So i put these keypairs (player, score) into an arraylist. From there i can get the values out into a listview.
This is just an example.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor scoreEditor = myScores.edit();
        scoreEditor.putString("PLAYER", "Thomas");
        scoreEditor.putString("SCORE", "5");
        scoreEditor.commit();


        final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        Map<String, ?> items = myScores.getAll();

        for(String s : items.keySet()){
            HashMap<String,String> hmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hmap.put("PLAYER", s);
            hmap.put("SCORE", items.get(s).toString());

            LIST.add(hmap);
        }

        Toast.makeText(Start.this, "LIST size: "+LIST.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

For me it would also be okay if i store these data like this:

```
scoreEditor.putString("DATA", "Thomas" + "-" + "5");
```

and put that into `ArrayList<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();`

but i don't know how to do it.

Could you guys help me with this?

**Edit:** So i could go another way as Haphazard suggested. I put together this code, but i don't know if this is the way to do it. I haven't tested it yet, as sg is wrong with the sharedpreferences and i am still trying to figure it out.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor scoreEditor = myScores.edit();
scoreEditor.putString("DATA", "Thomas" + "-" + "5");
scoreEditor.commit();


HashSet<String> hset=new HashSet<String>();
hset.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) myScores.getAll());

ArrayList<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>(hset);
```

Comment: When you have a force close, you should first look at the logcat and see where the problem is and the nature of the exception that forces close.

Answer (score 3):

The `SharedPreferences` `Editor` does not accept Lists but it does accept [Sets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).  You could convert your List into a `HashSet` or something similar and store it like that.  When your read it back, convert it into an `ArrayList`, sort it if needed and you're good to go.

Please note that the Set has to be a set of Strings so you will have to stick with your `"Thomas" + "-" + "5"` setup.

Edit: To your new update, I was thinking more of something like

```
//Retrieve the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();
```

That code is untested, but it should work

EDIT: If your API level is below the `get/setStringSet()` level then you can try this:

1) Turn your list of high scores into a delimited string.  That means if you had ["Tom, 1", "Ed, 5"] you could loop through it and turn it into a String like "Tom, 1|Ed, 5".  You can easily store that using `setString(..)`.

2) When you want to read the values back, perform a `getString(..)` and then `String.split("|")` to get the original list back.  Well, it returns an array but that can be converted to a list easily enough.

Comment: I updated now. Sorry, the sharedpreferences part results in force close and i am trying to figure the reason out.

Comment: 1. How to get the listofExistingScores?


2. getStringSet and putStringSet do not seem to be supported. I know it's here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)), but Eclipse doesn't recognize them. Probably, because i am programming under API lvl 11 (7).